# Product attribute is not updating in observer

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have a script like following

```
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app("default");
Mage::app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('sku','headlight1');
$productCollection->load();

foreach($productCollection as $_product) 
{     
   echo $_product->getPrice();   
        echo "----";
   echo $_product->getwholesaleprice(); 
        echo "<br>";

   $wholesalePrice = (float)(($_product->getPrice())*5)/100;
   echo "Wholesale price>>>".$wholesalePrice;
   echo "<br><br>";

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId());
    $product->setData('wholesaleprice', $wholesalePrice)->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'wholesaleprice'); 
}
```

This works well running in magento root, but same code does not work in Observer for `catalog_product_save_before` event.

In config.xml I have following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Priceupdate>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Namespace_Priceupdate>
    </modules>
   <global>
        <models>
            <priceupdate>
                <class>Namespace_Priceupdate_Model</class>
            </priceupdate>            
        </models>     
        <events>        
             <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                     <priceupdate>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_Priceupdate_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>updateWholeSalePrice</method>
                     </priceupdate>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>       
        </events>       
   </global>            
</config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you code works in the observer, but there is a catch. You are observing `catalog_product_save_before` and in there you create an other instance of the product

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId());
```

and make changes on that one.  And you changes are saved in the db.
But the current instance of the product (the one passed to the observer) does not know about the changes you made. It still contains the old data and this old data gets saved over the values you just modified.

I think you should use this code in your observer.

```
public function updateWholeSalePrice($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $_product->getPrice();   
    $_product->getWholesaleprice(); 
    $wholesalePrice = (float)(($_product->getPrice())*5)/100;
    $product->setWholesaleprice($wholesalePrice);
}
```

The code above means that you just modify the value of the attribute `wholesaleprice` and let magento do it's saving with this new value.

Answer (score 1):

To load an observer you need to set following files

config.xml file

```
<global>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <npm_product>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Npm_Product_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>before_product_save</method>
                    </npm_product>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>
        </events>
<global>
```

And observer.php

```
<?php
class Npm_Product_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function before_product_save($observer)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes the difference in my code and your code?